# HTML Input Element has no method 'isValid'

Tags: javascript, html, events

I have a javascript class `c` and I am trying to call its method `isValid()` on the `onClick` event of a input submit button. I have `c` in a set of script tags below my submit button currently. When I click on the submit button, I get

`Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLInputElement> has no method 'isValid'`

After some messing around, I try placing the same submit button at the bottom of the page, below the class script. This allows the method to be called correctly.

Here's my javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var c = {
        container : $('#c_c'),
        r1 : 0,
        r2 : 0,
        c_i : "",
        createCaptcha : function(){
            var newHtml;

            this.r1 = this.randomNumber(10);
            this.r2 = this.randomNumber(10);
            // alert(this.r1 + this.r2);

            newHtml += "<p>What is " + this.r1 + " plus " + this.r2 + "?<br/><input type='text' name='c'></p>";

            this.container.html(newHtml);
        },
        isValid : function(){
            // alert(this.r1);
            this.c_i = $('input[name="c"]');
            if (this.r1 + this.r2 == this.c_i.val()) {
                alert('correct!');
                return true;
            } else{
                alert('incorrect =[');
                return false;
            }
        },
        randomNumber : function(max){ return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max+1)); }
    }
    c.createCaptcha();
</script>
```

And here is my button:

```
<input id="form_0001_ao_submit_input" type="button" name="SUBMIT" value="Submit" style="color:#fff; font-size: 18px; height: 30px; width: 250px; background-color: #00a94f;" onClick="c.isValid();">
```

I also have a span with an ID on the page. This is what is referenced in `createCaptcha()` (Sorry I missed this vital piece of info =[):

```
<span id="c_c"></span>
```

So here's what the page looks like:

```
<span id="c_c"></span>
<input id="form_0001_ao_submit_input" type="button" name="SUBMIT" value="Submit" style="color:#fff; font-size: 18px; height: 30px; width: 250px; background-color: #00a94f;" onClick="c.isValid();">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var c = {
        container : $('#c_c'),
        r1 : 0,
        r2 : 0,
        c_i : "",
        createCaptcha : function(){
            var newHtml;

            this.r1 = this.randomNumber(10);
            this.r2 = this.randomNumber(10);
            // alert(this.r1 + this.r2);

            newHtml += "<p>What is " + this.r1 + " plus " + this.r2 + "?<br/><input type='text' name='c'></p>";

            this.container.html(newHtml);
        },
        isValid : function(){
            // alert(this.r1);
            this.c_i = $('input[name="c"]');
            if (this.r1 + this.r2 == this.c_i.val()) {
                alert('correct!');
                return true;
            } else{
                alert('incorrect =[');
                return false;
            }
        },
        randomNumber : function(max){ return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max+1)); }
    }
    c.createCaptcha();
</script>
```

It definitely seems like having the call to the method of the not yet defined `c` object is not allowing the method to run, which makes sense.

What would be the best way to aleviate this, without having to move the script to the top of the page (as performance wise, js is better placed at the bottom)? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you considered moving your javascript to a js file instead of embedded in the HTML?

Comment: Seems to work at the bottom already, see http://jsbin.com/ozurax/1/edit

Comment: Do you happen to have an html element that is assigned the id of 'c'? That can cause the DOM to try to execute a function against the html element instead of the javascript variable.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I forgot about including that part. I will edit the original question.

Comment: @AaronKurtzhals - What would that do? It would be the same as embedding it into the HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do the following changes to your code:

1. Remove var "c" from the global scope. This scope should be used very carefully. Imagine if another javascript file also declared a var named "c" (shame on them) using this scope. It would've been overwritten by you.
2. Remove the "onClick" attribute declared directly on the input.
3. Since you're using jQuery, you could declare your code inside the "ready" method (which is executed right after the DOM is loaded - no matter where your place your script. Like this:

```
    $(function(){
        //c now is inside a function, so it's not declared on the global scope
        var c = {
           // ... your code
        };  

        //creates the captcha when the DOM is loaded
        c.createCaptcha(); 

        $('#form_0001_ao_submit_input').click(function(){
            c.isValid();
        });

    });
```

Also consider extracting your javascript code to another file (and import it as you did with jQuery) so the browsers will be able to cache it for faster loading.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you for the answer! I selected it because it answered my question in full and provided best practice on scope that I didn't explicitly ask for. Thanks again @MarlonBernades!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can add an event listener to the input object later in your code.
With JQuery:

```
$("#form_0001_ao_submit_input").click(function() { c.isValid(); });
```

(after declaring c)

Comment: I would do this normally, but I have another function to run directly after the c.isValid() method. I guess the question here would be, if I added an event listener, would the function be run before what is defined in the `onClick` event in the button?

Comment: I don't know why this just dawned on me, but I strung together the other functions, one after another, after the `c.isValid();` method. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score -1):

Your `input` element is trying to access the global variable `c`.

Simply change your JavaScript to explicitly declare `c` as a global variable as such:

```
window.c = {
    ...
};
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/ud66S/1/